# Why is my first column being skipped on input?

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a `.csv` file which I want to load into a table via MySQL. If I have my SQL query as:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
playerID VARCHAR(40),
class VARCHAR(40),
system VARCHAR(40),
lvl INT,
build VARCHAR(40),
...
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Then my table consists of

`id  playerID  class system  lvl build ...`

`1    monk      ps4    70     0   77   ...`

whereas if I include the `id` at the end of the `CREATE TABLE` query:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
playerID VARCHAR(40),
class VARCHAR(40),
system VARCHAR(40),
lvl INT,
build VARCHAR(40),
...
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

then the `id` field correctly auto-increments and the playerID, class, etc. are correctly entered:

`playerID  class system  lvl build ...`

`Player1   monk   ps4    70   0    ...`

In either case, the way I am reading in the data is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/data.csv'
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED  BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

So I am assuming the problem is that I am reading the data in with `id` being sent to the first argument in the `.csv` file, but how do I edit my queries to input an auto-incrementing Primary Key as the first column in the table?

EDIT:

The basic syntax of the `.csv` file is:

`playerID, class, system, lvl, build, ...`

`player1, monk, ps4, 70, dual, ...`

Comment: Format of the CSV would be useful. I think what you are saying is your CSV doesn't have ID's and that you want the DB to generate them?

Comment: yes, I will edit and add a basic syntax of lines for the .csv file but it follows the second convention of 'PlayerID, class, system, lvl, build, ... '

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a column list to handle cases when the CSV doesn't align with the table schema, for example

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/data.csv'
INTO TABLE table_name (playerID, class, system, lvl, build)
FIELDS TERMINATED  BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: If I do this, will it automatically generate a column 1 which is the `id`?